Constraints added by migration do not work when updating with CrudRepository
When I start Spring Boot app (H2 DB used for some tests, but the issue can be more generic), I run some migration scripts creating constraints:
CREATE TABLE student (id INT NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE friends (id INT NOT NULL, studentId1 INT NOT NULL, studentId2 INT NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE FRIENDS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (studentId1) 
REFERENCES student(ID );

ALTER TABLE FRIENDS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (studentId2)
REFERENCES student(ID); 

Then there are added items by using Spring JPA Repository and Entity defined like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "friends")
public class FriendsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    private Long studentId1;
    private Long studentId2;
    ....//
} 

Adding performed by call friendsRepository.save(entityToSave); where friendsRepository extends CrudRepository<FriendsEntity, Long>
When adding items by this way it seems that constraints do not work (I can add items with non-existing student ids). Does it means that when using CrudRepository then constraints added by migration scripts on start ignored/removed?

how are you sure your scripts ran exactly? Note you have a cut and paste mistake and are creating a fk from sttudentId1->Student twice.

@Chris - thanks for pointing to mistake - fixed. Regardint the script - it runs when starting Spring Boot app - it stored in data.sql file (\src\main\resources\data.sql - in the project)

runs- but where? Are you sure it is run against the database you are using for your tests?
Maybe turn on logging and try connecting to your DB through SQL tools to see what is happening

It runs on in-memory H2 database. I access to it via h2 console (localhost:8080/h2-console) . When I run SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS  - I don't see Foreign Key constraints added by script. But from other side - I succeed to add constraint by same commands manually

yes, but how are you seeing that this script was run at all- turn logging on

UPD : Found the issue : the data.sql script executes before Hibernate initialization -by default (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) . Setting pring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true   helped.

As your script is creating the tables, why is Hibernate loading an issue? You didn't give details on how you were running this script, but if you want it to run WITH JPA DDL generation (or ensure it is run after), you should use JPA properties to have it run the scripts rather than risk conflicts like this. See https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-database-schema-jpa/
